# "Maven Project" radio option is not showing in Jenkins (latest version 2.7.1 for Windows)

Tags: jenkins

"Maven Project" radio option is not showing in Jenkins (latest version 2.7.1 for Windows)

Steps:
- Open Jenkins server
- Click on New Item

The 'maven project' radio option is not available.

Though I've added (installed) "Maven Metadata Plugin for Jenkins CI Server" from Jenkin's "Manage Plugin" section.

Appreciate in advance for sooner reply on this.

Thanks,
Shiv

Comment: Did you try `Reload Configuration from Disk` on Manage Jenkins section ?

Comment: Yes I did it but no success. After that I've re-launched the Jenkins Sever page again.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

Check if you tick the enable checkbox for the maven plugin. If not enable it and restart the server again.

Comment: It worked... Kudo to tinkerbell and the community members. The 'Maven Integration plugin' was not installed implicitly. Once I did, issue got resolved.

Comment: @tinkerbell yes thank you! worked for me too after hours of troubleshooting lol

Answer (score 11):

To add Maven Project in New Item Page >

1. Goto **Manage Jenkins-> Manage Plugin**
2. Click on **Available Tab**
3. Search  **Unleash Maven Plugin**
4. Enable the **check-box, click on**

Answer (score 2):

Goto Manage Jenkins and then to Manage Plugins and the activate Maven Integration plugin, save and restart server. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Available plugins and filter with "Maven" , you can easily find Maven integration plugin.

[image]

install and restart Jenkins. you are good.

Answer (score 0):

The default and suggested plugins options at the beginning of the Jenkins installation often do not list the "Maven Integration" plugin. Hence, you need to download and install the "Maven Integration" plugin from the "Manage Jenkins"==> "Manage Plugins" option. Search for Maven, select the "Maven Integration" plugin and hola!!! You are done. Now the Maven Project option will be available to select under New Items...